# Angular *ngFor index doesn't update new value

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I made a timer than when it runs out it displays mcq with 4 choices. The answer is always in a different position. Once clicked or if time (a different timer for the question) runs out, the first timer starts again until another mcq pops up. Unfortunately, everything works except my choiceIndex. If I chose the second answer for the first question, no matter what answer I choose for the other questions it will always be `choiceIndex = 1` (second answer).

What is the problem?

question component typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, OnDestroy, HostListener, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Qa } from '../qa';
import { POSTALCODE } from "../postalCode";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question',
  templateUrl: './question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question.component.css']
})

export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() qas: Qa[];
  @Output() answerEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>;
  public displayQuestion: boolean;
  public question: Qa;
  public choiceIndex: number;
  public clicked: boolean;
  public answer: boolean;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Items created');
    this.displayQuestion = true;
    this.clicked = false;
    this.answer = true;
    console.log(
      this.question = POSTALCODE[Math.floor(Math.random()*POSTALCODE.length)]
    );
  }

  newQuestion() {
    this.displayQuestion = true;
    console.log(
      this.question = POSTALCODE[Math.floor(Math.random()*POSTALCODE.length)]
    );
    this.clicked = false;
  }
  deleteQuestion() {
    this.displayQuestion = false;
  }

  checkAnswer() {
    if(this.clicked && this.choiceIndex == this.question.answerIndex) {
      this.answer = true;
      this.correctAnswer();
      return true;
    }
    this.answer = false;
    this.incorrectAnswer();
    return false;
  }

  correctAnswer() {
    //DESTROY
    // this.answerEvent.emit(this.answer);
    this.deleteQuestion();
    console.log("CORRECT!");
  }

  incorrectAnswer() {
    //DESTROY + PUNISHMENT
    // this.answerEvent.emit(this.answer);
    this.deleteQuestion();
    console.log("INCORRECT!");
  }

  protected readonly POSTALCODE = POSTALCODE;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="displayQuestion" id="game">
  <div class="container unsolved">
    <div class="pair_items left">
      <h1 *ngIf="question" class="item">
        {{this.question.question}}
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="pair_items right">
      <button *ngFor="let choice of this.question.choices; index as i;" class="item" (click)="this.clicked = true; this.choiceIndex = i; this.checkAnswer();">
        {{choice}}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="this.clicked == true">
    <div class="container solved" *ngIf="this.checkAnswer()">
      CORRECT!
    </div>
    <div class="container solved" *ngIf="!this.checkAnswer()">
      INCORRECT!
    </div>
  </div>

  <app-timeLeft [answer]="answer" (timeExpiredEvent)="incorrectAnswer()"></app-timeLeft>
</div>
```

The problem is here:

```
<button *ngFor="let choice of this.question.choices; index as i;" class="item" (click)="this.clicked = true; this.choiceIndex = i; this.checkAnswer();">
```

`i` only registers the first value and for the other choices it doesn't update. This messes with my method `checkAnswer()`

Comment: Can you create a minimum reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: don't use `this` in the template HTML, just refer it as `questions`

Answer (score 1):

I took a liberty and simplified your code a little bit. I tried to remove code repetitions and get rid of function calls in templates, which can be quite cumbersome in Angular.

Your approach with setting everything in template it's not the greatest idea as you are kind of losing control over it and it's bit difficult to debug.

Here's the template with some changes:

```html
<div *ngIf="displayQuestion" id="game">
  <div class="container unsolved">
    <div class="pair_items left">
      <h1 *ngIf="question" class="item">
        {{this.question.question}}
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="pair_items right">
      <!-- checkAnswer now accepts index as parameter and also handle clicked flag -->
      <button 
        *ngFor="let choice of this.question.choices; index as i;"
        class="item"
        (click)="this.checkAnswer(i);"
      >
        {{choice}}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="this.clicked">
    <!-- Calling checkAnswer() in *ngIf is bit strange, especially when this.answer holds the result -->
    <!-- And there's no need to repeat everything when you're just changing a string -->
    <div class="container solved">
      {{ this.answer ? 'CORRECT!' : 'INCORRECT!' }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <app-timeLeft [answer]="answer" (timeExpiredEvent)="handleAnswer(false)"></app-timeLeft>
</div>
```

And the TS. I removed duplicates and also moved most of click the functionality from the template to the `checkAnswer` function. This way it's easier to read and debug.

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, OnDestroy, HostListener, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Qa } from '../qa';
import { POSTALCODE } from "../postalCode";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question',
  templateUrl: './question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question.component.css']
})

export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() qas: Qa[];
  @Output() answerEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>;
  
  public displayQuestion: boolean;
  public question: Qa;
  public choiceIndex: number;
  public clicked: boolean;
  public answer: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newQuestion();
  }

  // DRY - Don't repeat yourself
  newQuestion() {
    this.displayQuestion = true;
    this.clicked = false;
    // I'm not sure about this part though, I guess it should be this.qas instead of POSTALCODE, correct?
    this.question = POSTALCODE[Math.floor(Math.random()*POSTALCODE.length)];
    console.log('Items created');   
    console.log('QUESTION:', this.question);   
  }

  deleteQuestion() {
    this.displayQuestion = false;
  }

  // Use one method to mark clicked, set choice index and if it's correct
  checkAnswer(choice: number) {
    console.log('CHOICE INDEX:', choice);
    this.clicked = true;
    // Make sure that choice and answer indexes are equal and both consider
    // arrays starting from index 0
    const isCorrect = choice === this.question.answerIndex;
    
    this.answer = isCorrect;
    this.handleAnswer(isCorrect);

    return isCorrect;
  }

  // Once again, too much repetition just to propagate one boolean to the parent => replaces both correctAnswer() and incorrectAnswer() methods
  handleAnswer(isCorrect: boolean) {
    //DESTROY
    // this.answerEvent.emit(this.answer);
    this.deleteQuestion();
    console.log(isCorrect ? "CORRECT!" : "INCORRECT!");
  }

  protected readonly POSTALCODE = POSTALCODE;
}
```

Honestly, I don't know what causes your issue, I hope there are no hidden catches in the code you did not provide. But this should be working the way it's intended,  I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2xutd7?devToolsHeight=33&file=src/main.ts) with what was reproducible, see for yourself.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks! I just started with Angular so it is a bit confusing but I'm getting there. And you are correct, this.qas instead of POSTCODE, you fixed another one of my confusions.